# Why the objective function in optimization does not follow dimensional rule?

Tags: optimization, dimensional-analysis

I have seen few studies where the objective function tries to minimize two different variables (let's say $a$ and $b$) that are of different dimensions using a superposition rule. For example, this is what they do:

$$f = \min \left[ (a_{estimated} - a_{observed})^2 + (b_{estimated} - b_{observed})^2 \right]$$

What's your comment regarding this practice? Am I missing something in above interpretation that suggests this is mathematically inconsistent?

I thought this could have been mathematically consistent if we divided their difference by their variances, but that would actually go against the minimization principle because a higher variance would artificially decrease the objective function $f$, when it should be opposite.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack.

Multi-objective optimization is significantly more complex than optimizing a single objective function (for instance there are whole families of solutions along the Pareto frontier) so it is common practice to combine all of the terms you desire to be small into a single objective, in a more-or-less ad-hoc way.

Usually you use a parameter to scale the two terms:

$$\min_x\ \|f(x)\|^2 + \lambda \|g(x)\|^2$$

where $\lambda$ is chosen to rate the relative "importance" of the two terms. This $\lambda$ can be assigned whatever units are necessary to make the two terms commensurate (which of course does not change the fact that the value selected is often ad-hoc.) Your objective is the special case $\lambda=1$.

EDIT: If you're confused about vector space dimension (rather than unit dimension) note that the optimization problem in the OP is *really*

$$f = \min \|a_{estimated} - a_{observed}\|^2 + \|b_{estimated} - b_{observed}\|^2$$
for some norm $\|\|$ (usually the two-norm but, increasingly, the one-norm thanks to its sparsification properties.) Some authors write $(v-w)^2$ for vectors $v$ and $w$ to mean $\|v-w\|^2$, which surely causes confusion.

Comment: I agree regarding what you said, and I also thought about those weighting factors as such that may be used to bring about their consistent dimensionality, but it's a flimsy argument. I did not find any source that could help support that thought, so I thought about asking it here. Although, you did not answer the crust of my question, which is the inconsistency in dimensions of two multi-objective functions.

Comment: @user11: I thought I did: you pick whatever units for lamda make the dimensions consistent. There is nothing deep going on here: you have two quantities you want to make small, so you minimize an arbitrary linear combination, with the coefficients chosen in an extremely problem-specific way.